# Align DIVs in TD to Bottom

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to align two DIVs in a Table TD to the bottom of that table, but for some reason the DIV on the left is refusing to budge. I have tried various alignment methods etc but it will not move to the bottom.  The email I am designing is meant to be responsive so I have to ensure that when the window is narrowed, it still works.

JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/hirenshah/rdux8vkg/

HTML:

```
<body bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                <![endif]-->
                <table class="container" width="300px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width: 600px; background-color: white; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <!-- Header Table Start -->
                            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom; font-size: 0;">
                                        <div class="headercolumnright">
                                            <img src="http://hirenshah.co.uk/poc/logo.png" width="50%"/></div>
                                        <div class="headercolumnleft ">Reference: 123456789</div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- Header Table End -->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <![endif]-->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
    .container {
        width:600px !important;
    }
    .headercolumnright {
        text-align:right !important;
    }
}
.headercolumnleft {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    float: left;
    font-size:12pt;
}
.headercolumnright {
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    float: right;
    font-size:12pt;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}
div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Like this? ----> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdux8vkg/3/)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py, not quite because that stops the responsive part working.

Comment: If you are marking up HTML for an email, I would stay away from floats.  Changes are some email clients will not render it well.  Stick to nested tables is the safest approach for creating email layouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the Left DIV before the RIGHT div and that should fix it...

```
<tr>
 <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:bottom; font-size: 0;"> 
 <div class="headercolumnleft ">Reference: 123456789</div>
 <div class="headercolumnright">
   <img src="http://hirenshah.co.uk/poc/logo.png" width="50%"/></div>                                 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

I tried it in your JSFiddle and it worked fine.

Cliff.

Comment: It much better to split css and html. And if you've already put together a fiddle, why not post it in the answer?

Comment: I just tried that but the Reference part is still at the top, whereas I want it all aligned to the bottom. Doing that also breaks the float, because I wanted the right to go on top of the left. http://jsfiddle.net/hirenshah/rdux8vkg/5/

Comment: I didn't put one together I just edited hshah's one to prove to myself that I wasn't going to give a crap answer.